# Pass array of non-nullable strings as array of nullable strings

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that takes in an `Array<String?>`:

```
fun doStuff(words: Array<String?>) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way I can pass in a `Array<String>` to this function? As-is the compiler is giving me a "type mismatch" error.

```
private val SOME_WORDS = arrayOf("I", "want", "to", "use", "these")

doStuff(SOME_WORDS) // throws a type-mismatch error
```

Preferably I'd like to avoid making `SOME_WORDS` an `arrayOf<String?>(...)` if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [`out`-projected](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) `Array<out String?>`:

```
fun doStuff(words: Array<out String?>) { /* ... */ }
```

[Arrays in Kotlin are invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-arrays), meaning that `Array<A>` and `Array<B>` are not subtypes of each other for any different `A` and `B`, including `String` and `String?`, and they cannot be assigned and passed as arguments in place of each other.

Using an `out`-projection `Array<out String?>` makes the function accept not only `Array<String?>` but also arrays with subtypes of `String?`. Basically, since the type is `final`, there's only one such subtype, and it is `String` (the non-null one, without `?`).

[image: type variance diagram]

<sup>The picture is taken from: [A Whirlwind Tour of the Kotlin Type Hierarchy](http://natpryce.com/articles/000818.html))</sup>

So, the function will accept `Arrray<String>` as well. But you won't be able to put nullable values into the array (that's how the projection works), so the type safety (and null-safety) are preserved.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is **variance** here. `String` is a subtype of its nullable friend `String?` but in Kotlin this doen't mean `Array<String>` is a subtype of `Array<String?>` because arrays are **invariant**.
(In Java this is not the case, arrays are covariant by default)

If you have a function like yours which expects an argument of type `Array<String?>` you can only pass `Array<String?>`, thus `Array<String>` isn't possible! If you want to enable your method to also handle these arrays do this:

```
fun doStuff(words: Array<out String?>) {
    // ...
}
```

This makes the array `words` **covariant** and subtypes of `Array<String?>` are allowed to be passed.

Be aware, that only functions like `get()` are accessible for such "out-projected" arrays. The Parameter `words` is said to be a **Producer** of `String?`.

If you want to learn more about it, have a look at the official [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [out type projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) since the generic type `Array<String>` extends `Any` rather than `Array<String?>` in Kotlin, for example:

```
//                        v--- use out type projection here
fun doStuff(words: Array<out String?>) {
   // ...
}
```

[image: Generic Inheritance]

When use the [out type projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) in Kotlin is like as [upper bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) `? extends T` in Java. and the `String` is a subset of the `String?` in Kotlin, so the `Array<String>` extends `Array<String?>` in Kotlin. As you can see the left side of inheritance diagram is the [upper bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) inheritance.

[image: Upper bounded wildcard]