# Type mismatch. Required: Array<Uri>! Found: Array<Uri?>

Tags: android, kotlin, types, syntax

The `?` and `!!` syntax is very confusing in kotlin! I'm declaring a value callback as a private member of my activity:

```
private lateinit var mFilePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>
```

And I assign it on `onShowFileChooser` on onCreate method like so:

```
    override fun onShowFileChooser(
    webView: WebView?,
    filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
    fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
): Boolean {
    mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback!! //Assigned here
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    val PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE)
    return true
}
```

But when I try to use it in `onActivityResult` like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(data != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val resultsArray = arrayOfNulls<Uri>(1)
        resultsArray[0] = data.data
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultsArray)
        Log.d("ACTIVITY RESULT", data.data.toString())
    } else {
        Log.d("ACTIVITY RESULT", "Cannot get file path.")
    }
}
```

I get the following error in `onRecieveValue` function call: `Type mismatch. Required: Array<Uri>! Found: Array<Uri?>` This is so confusing!

Comment: Just put the `!!` at the end of `Array<Uri>`. Something like this `Array<Uri>!!`

Comment: @Ashish where exactly do i put the `!!` ?

Comment: @Ashish where? Which paramter are you talking about?

Comment: @Ashish Yeah, I removed the `?` from there still same error :(

Comment: Please Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343348/10182897) answer. Now you understand It says one of your uri is empty that's why it says `Array<Uri?>`.

Comment: @Ashish Yeah reading it! I think i did something wrong in `val resultsArray = arrayOfNulls<Uri>(1)
        resultsArray[0] = data.data
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultsArray)` these lines as there is still error there.

Comment: There is explanation for your Question if you understand what is problem and other stuff please Mark it as answer and upvote.

Comment: I will after I get my error fixed

Answer (score 4):

All I had to do is cast results arrays as `Array<Uri>`:

`mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultsArray as Array<Uri>)`

Answer (score 3):

1. `arrayOfNulls<Uri>(1)` returns `Array<Uri?>` because its elements can be null and are null to start with.
2. Setting an element with `resultsArray[0] = data.data` doesn't change the type (why would it?).
3. So you are passing an `Array<Uri?>` to `mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue` which expects an `Array<Uri>` (an array whose elements are all `Uri` which can't be null).

Instead of the cast as in your own answer, just create the array of the correct type to start with:

```
val uri = data.data
if (uri != null) {
    val resultsArray = arrayOf<Uri>(uri)
    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultsArray)
    Log.d("ACTIVITY RESULT", uri.toString()) // why toString?
} else {
    // your original code doesn't cover this case
    // so decide what to do here
}
```

Note that if you just do

```
val resultsArray = arrayOf<Uri>(data.data)
```

you should ideally get a warning because `data.data` can be null, but [it doesn't seem to be properly marked as `@Nullable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()).

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is very strict on types. As [Alexey Romanov already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131303/6296561), when you create an array with `arrayOfNulls`, that creates an `Array<Uri?>`.

A nullable type can contain the type itself, but a non-null type cannot contain null. Conversion from `Array<Uri>` to `Array<Uri>?` is fine for an instance. However, due to variance in generics, you can't pass `Array<Uri>` as an argument of the type `Array<Uri?>`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45866466/6296561).

You need an `Array<Uri>!`. The `!` is a special syntax you can't use, but that indicates a platform call to a method with either a return type or argument with an undefined nullability type. What's important to keep in mind here is that you can pass a non-null type to it, or a nullable one for that matter. `!` just means the compiler doesn't know, so it doesn't strictly enforce null-safety in the same way as it usually would.

For an instance, consider this method:

```
public void someMethod(String str) {}
```

Which will have the `str` parameter interpreted as a `String!` in Kotlin. Add `@Nullable` and it's `String?`, or `@NonNull` and it's `String`.

The key point, as outlined in the previous link, the method is interpreted as a potentially nullable array of non-null URIs:

```
Array   <Uri>                            !
^ Type  ^ Generic type (here: non-null)  ^ signifies the type (NOT the generic type) is potentially nullable (not normally useable)
```

Anyway, the main issue here is that you're trying to pass `Array<Uri>` to `Array<Uri?>` - as outlined in the post I linked earlier, if you want to support that, you need to add `out Uri?` as the parameter. The method being a part of the stdlib means you can't do that.

If you're **completely** sure you'll never get a null type in the array after it's populated, you can, as you outlined in your answer, cast it. That being said, I'd highly recommend you use the safe cast operator in combination with let to avoid a crash if you get null. In case you didn't check, [that can happen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()):

> ```
> Returns
> URI          The URI of the data this intent is targeting or null.
> ```

You can go with something like Alexey Romanov mentioned - Run an if-else statement to check if data is null, and put it directly into an array using `arrayOf` if it isn't null. That being said, you should still handle `getData()` returning null, even if you go with the `as` approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the specific case of cast from `Array<T?>` to `Array<T>`, `as?` is useless because they have the same erasure. It's also `Array<Uri!>!`, not `Array<Uri>!`, which complicates a bit (that's why I added explicit `arrayOf<Uri>` in my reply).

Comment: The error included ` Array<Uri>!`, which is why I went off that. As for `as?`, I haven't done much casting between nullable and non-nullable variants - why is there no difference? Is there no null safety for the array types when it's cast at runtime?

Comment: Basically: 1. `x as? T` reduces to `if (x is T) (x as T) else null`; 2. `is` can only verify JVM types (with a few hacks for `MutableList` etc., I think), and `Array<Uri>` and `Array<Uri?>` are both `Uri[]` in JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` and `!!` syntax is very confusing in kotlin!

They are not Confusion both Symbol have different Meaning Kotlin.

To Explain Both Symbol :

Lets Take :

Symbol **?** and it known as [Safe Nullable cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator)

This Symbol work as Nullable. Means when you try to assign Value in Kotlin

```
val myString : String? = null
```

and Difference

```
val myString : String = null // This will give Error So you have to put string with null value (e.g.[""]).
```

and The Other Symbol **!!** and it is called as [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator):

It means Not Nullable.

When you pass have to Pass Value according to it's datatype. Means if it asks for string you have to pass String.

But when it receives null value or wrong response.

Then it will give you

> [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException)

If you have any query then just comment it down i'll clear for you.

Comment: You're wrong. There's no `!!` in this case - it's `!`, which is a potentially nullable platform call. It's not null-safety. `?` is NOT known as the safe nullable cast operator. When used at the end of a type, it signifies a nullable type. When at the end of the `as` keyword, it's the safe nullable cast operator, which returns null if the cast fails. `?.` is a null-safe call, which doesn't call the right side if the left side is null.