# Return an Array<out String>? in Kotlin

Tags: string, variables, kotlin

I'm trying to read a list of string from a file, which is structured as a list:

```
ElemA
ElemB
ElemC
```

I need to save into this variable, which is defined as:

```
private var history: Array<out String>?
```

I made this method, but it doesn't works because it requires an **Array?** as output, but it founds an Array<(out) Any!>!

```
private fun loadHistory(): Array<out String>? {
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    File("history").forEachLine { list.add(it) }
    return list.toArray()
}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866466/pass-array-of-non-nullable-strings-as-array-of-nullable-strings

Comment: Try using `list.toTypedArray()` instead of `list.toArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @jsamol in the comments.

You should use `toTypedArray()` instead of `toArray()` to get an array of the specific type.([ref](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html))

`toArray()` returns new array of type `Array<Any?>`. ([ref](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-abstract-collection/to-array.html))

```
private fun loadHistory(): Array<out String>? {
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    File("history").forEachLine { list.add(it) }
    return list.toTypedArray()
}
```